# NSNotification in Cocos2d iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

i have a button in the start screen of my game,when the user tap the button it will redirected to the next page, i calling a notification in this button click event ,the code for this is

```
- (void)switchsounds
{
    CCLOG(@"hiii");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadvieweyes" object:nil];
    CCTransitionJumpZoom *transition = [CCTransitionJumpZoom transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]];

    // Tell the director to run the transition
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:transition];


}
```

the above code is the button click function

on the next page of init statmnet i put this code to get the functonalty of the button event

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(viewreloadedeyes) name:@"reloadvieweyes" object:nil];
}
return self;

}



-(void)viewreloadedeyes
{

 CCLOG(@"hiii");

}
```

i didnt get the cclog in button click event aswell as the function in the next page.but the page redirction is done with the button lcick.what is the problm with my code.how to get nsnofication from one page to anothe in a button click.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your second snippet of code targets the HelloWorldLayer?

Answer (score 1):

Notification selectors [require the NSNotification* parameter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Registering.html). Change your code to this:

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
  selector:@selector(viewreloadedeyes:)
      name:@"reloadvieweyes"
    object:nil];
 }
 return self;

}

-(void)viewreloadedeyes:(NSNotification*)notification
{
 CCLOG(@"hiii");
}
```

Comment: It's better to add the NSNotification as first argument but this is not necessary. Here the issue is elsewhere I think.

Answer (score 0):

heyy guys,i found the solution, i just put the notification inside the view transtion like this

```
- (void)switchsounds
{
    CCLOG(@"hiii");

    CCTransitionJumpZoom *transition = [CCTransitionJumpZoom transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]];


 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadvieweyes" object:nil];
    // Tell the director to run the transition


    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:transition];


}
```

now its woking perfectly.Thanks.